# How is the emitter current kept constant in common base BJT?

Tags: bjt

While studying the output characteristics of a common base BJT I had the following question:

How is the emitter current kept constant? Do we ignore the early effect, if so then why?

Comment: I must admit that I do not understand the question. The question implies that the emitter current would be constant - however, this is not the case, because this current reacts upon the input signal. Otherwise, the EARLY voltage would not play any role..

Comment: I may be able to offer a simple way to imagine about the Early Effect for the CB config. The Early Effect affects \$\beta\$. If you have lots of base resistance present, as in CE for example, then the non-linear variations in recombination current causes a varying non-linear voltage drop across the Thevenin base resistance and this adds a non-linear (bad) component to the output signal. But if you nail the base down to a voltage source with low impedance, the \$\beta\$ variation from the Early Effect doesn't matter much as there's no resistance to cause a non-linear variable voltage drop.

Answer (score 1):

One way of looking at it is that in common base, current gain is (approaches) 1, so that the voltage gain is dependent on the load impedance on the collector.

Therefore to maximise gain, the collector load impedance should be infinite : a constant current source.

So really it is the **collector** current that is maintained constant; this implies an (approximately) constant emitter current.